# How can I retain a PublisherAdView on an orientation change?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, ads, android-orientation

I'm using a [PublisherAdView](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/doubleclick/PublisherAdView.html) to display a banner ad in my app. When the app starts I create the PublisherAdView, add it to a layout, and request an ad. I would like to display the same ad that has already been requested after an orientation change. Currently the PublisherAdView gets destroyed and recreated on an orientation change, so I lose the ad that was requested.

Here is how I create the PublisherAdView in a fragment:

```
PublisherAdView banner_ad_view = new PublisherAdView(getActivity());
banner_ad_view.setAdUnitId(ad_unit_id);
banner_ad_view.setAdSizes(new AdSize(ad_width, ad_height));
```

Here is how I add the PublisherAdView to my fragment layout:

```
int id = R.id.fragment_banner_ad_container;
RelativeLayout ad_container = (RelativeLayout) fragment_view.findViewById(id);
ad_container.addView(banner_ad_view);
```

Here is how I load an ad into the PublisherAdView (using [PublisherAdRequest](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/doubleclick/PublisherAdRequest.html)):

```
banner_ad_view.loadAd(ad_request);
```

I have been trying to avoid using `android:configChanges` as I do have different resources to manage based on orientation.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

On android manifest in the activity that you want

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden" >
```

and in the main activity:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
    }
}
```

Thats work for me